# IIS .Net Website hangs even after restart IIS/Machine

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis

I have a .Net application hosted in IIS 10 running on Windows Service 2019. Sometimes the website stops responding (usually when running E2E tests). Even after restarting Website/Application Pool/IIS/Machine it doesn't work.

Looking in Event Viewer I see errors like these:

- `Forms authentication failed for the request. Reason: The ticket supplied has expired`
- `Failed to stop a listening channel for protocol 'http' at allotted time from worker process serving application pool`
- A process serving application pool exceeded time limits during shut down

In HTTPERR files I see a lot of messages containing `Connection_Abandoned_By_ReqQueue` and `Connection_Dropped`

In inetpub log files I can't see any relevant, just the url requests.

To add more information, we have signalr installed and sometimes errors appear in the events, errors with messages like:
`The user identity cannot change during an active SignalR connection.`

Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: Try the hang related labs created by Tess, https://www.tessferrandez.com/postindex/ and then you might get some hints on how to debug the issue on your machine. Many of the error messages might be gone as soon as you resolve the hang issue.

Comment: There are many reasons for the hang, you can try to increase the worker processes limit by going to the Properties section of the application pool on IIS, If that doesn't solve the problem, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.